# Command start-database failed on Glassfish

Tags: glassfish

[Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEBO4.png)

derby.log

```
Mon Oct 31 22:57:04 IST 2016 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Mon Oct 31 22:57:05 IST 2016 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.10.2.0 - (1582446) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527
Mon Oct 31 22:57:05 IST 2016 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.10.2.0 - (1582446) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Please don't put images of something that is text.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: The log shows that the command succeeded and the database has started. The response from the command prompt may not be correct. Did you verify that the database had not started yourself?